Disabling the cursor from blinking in Visual Studio 2022
I wanted to know how you can disable the cursor from blinking in Visual Studio 2022 since I find it really annoying. Here's an image of how my cursor currently is. As you can see from the picture I am also using the VsVim extension as well and I was wondering if this will also effect the option I have to change to disable the cursor from blinking.


The cursor blinking is a feature of VsVim.
It uses the cursor blink settings of Windows, so you can just go to:
Control Panel -> Keyboard -> Cursor blink rate
And set the Cursor blink rate to "None"

Thanks, it seems to have got rid of the issue.
